# Sitecore jss headless mode with multiple sites

Tags: jss

I have downloaded jss proxy and configured my site to run in headless mode. How to configure multiple sites with different domains

Answer (score 1):

Are you planning multiple jss app for multiple sites or single jss app for multiple sites?

First scenario, take different builds and keep it in different folders in the proxy server. Then define same number of config (config.js).

Install vhost (npm install vhost) in the proxy server , which can be used to conditionally take config to be executed based on the hostname.

Comment: Thanks @Renjit, We have single jss app with multiple sites

Comment: For the second scenario (jss app with multiple site), defining multiple configs for each site with different api host. Tried to use same api host for all sites with query string sitename 'sc_site' but the General link has issue, its generating urls with sitecore host name. Is it mandatory to have separate api host for all sites?